# How I Can add checkbox in mvc 5?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

please how to do checkbox that is named in my model public bool

`decision{get;set;}` ans that can takes one of the value checkbox 'refus' or

'accepte' that's mean

```
decision==false//that is refus 

decision==true//that is accepte
```

1. how to do it in the view
2. in the model
3. in the controllor

please help me i needed for my project .

Answer (score 1):

## View

```
<input type ="checkbox" @(Model.Accept ? "checked" : "") />
```

## Model

```
public class MyModel 
{
    public bool Accept {get; set;}
}
```

## Controller

This is where things get up to your implementation, an easy example would be to start with `ActionResult Index()`.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyModel{Accept = true};
    return View(model);
}
```

Your question was unclear and vague, so my answer is too. This should at least give you a start though.